# How to set value in UITextFied after the page is already loaded in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a native iOS project in which we have integrated react native. Here we have a screen A in native iOS(swift) and screen B in React-native.
When user is in screen A clicks on component and navigated to screen B. Inside screen B then user selects a option and passes that value to brigde between the two parts using NativeModules.
After that screen B gets dismissed and user is again able to see the screen A. The value which is passed through bridge can be accessed inside a function in screen A view controller, but when trying to set that value to UITextField getting error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Expecting to set the value which is received from screen B in screen A gets saved in UITextField to be utilised further

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu but you have probably created your view controller without using a storyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

This means that you tried to use an object which is nil.
E.g. you had a textField object (type of UITextField) and you tried to use:

```
textField!.text = "Some text"
```

Your textField is not yet initialized. Without code it's hard to say what's wrong but either you should have initilaized textField somewhere before:

```
textField = UITextField()
```

Or you should safely unwrap the field and **try** to set the value - if it's nil it still won't be set.

```
textField?.text = "Some text"
```